# Spinner while waiting for ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build in angularJS a select dropdown that has several thousand options.  While the view is getting built, the app hangs.  Is there a way to hide this dropdown behind a loading image until the options are finished being built?

Comment: This is slightly tangential to your question, but are you sure you'd want a dropdown box with 1000 options anyway? It might be more user friendly to refine these into different groups and dynamically populating the dropdown, depending on your application. You may want to try asynchronously loading the contents of the dropdown.

Comment: You can use `cg-busy` for your Angular Application.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-cloak 
Here is the documentation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Answer (score 0):

You may use a simple directive to map callbacks in the end of `ng-repeat`.
Here is also a quite rough [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/euwbnvzc/2/).

```
<h3 ng-repeat="name in names" repeat-end="onEnd()"></h3>

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $timeout){
            $scope.finish = false;
            $scope.onEnd = function(){
                $timeout(function(){
                        alert("finish")
                    $scope.finish = true;
                }, 1);
            };

        });

app.directive("repeatEnd", function(){
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    if (scope.$last) {
                        scope.$eval(attrs.repeatEnd);
                    }
                }
            };
        });
```